# Liferay asset publisher "move to recycle bin" link/button

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to add link for moving content into recycle bin next to "Edit" link in asset publisher's article detail.

Is there any possibility for constructing this link or I have to make my own portlet which will call this service:

```
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.moveArticleToTrash(userId, article)
```

Is there possibility to start workflow on this moving action?

Thanks,
Patrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by implementing own portlet which is providing functionality for moving articles into trash bin using this piece of code:

```
JournalArticle article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(articlePrimKey);
User user = PortalUtil.getUser(actionRequest);
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.moveArticleToTrash(user.getUserId(), article);
```

Then I created action url from asset publisher's template to this portlet.

Comment: Hi I have same requirement. How do you created action url  of custom portlet in adt? Can you provide please snippet for  constructing delete link ?